# Trying to change loop so that it copy and pastes a row in results sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this working code that loops through column D of sheet1, then finds matching values in column A of sheet 2, and finally puts a "Y" in sheet 3 if there is a match.

Instead of putting a 'Y' in sheet 3, i'm trying to get it to copy and paste the matching value and all subsequent rows from sheet 2.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub matchData()

Dim j, LastRow As Long
Dim answer, found As Range

LastRow = Workbooks("1").Sheets("1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 To LastRow
answer = Workbooks("1").Sheets("1").Range("D" & j).Value

Set found = Workbooks("1").Sheets("2").Columns("A:A").Find(what:=answer)

If found Is Nothing Then
    Workbooks("1").Sheets("3").Range("A" & j).Value = "N"
Else
    Workbooks("1").Sheets("3").Range("A" & j).Value = "Y"
End If

Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: Copy and paste to where?

Comment: Instead of "Y" being written into column A of sheet 3, I'm trying to get the matching value and adjacent row pasted in that same location.

Comment: in the same location? Do you mean that when you have found a match, you wnat to copy the whole row 1 to 1 to the other sheet?

Comment: "the matching value and all subsequent rows" - do you mean there may be >1 match for any given search term?

Comment: @aldert yes, right now in sheet 3 its putting "Y" or "N" in column A based on if the Sheet 1 column A value matches the sheet 2 column A value.  Instead of "Y", I want it to copy and paste the entire row of the value it matched with.

Comment: @Tim Williams no, I just mean the data in the same row as the matched value

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Sub matchData()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet
    Dim m As Variant, cDest As Range, c As Range
    
    Set wb = Workbooks("1")
    Set wsA = wb.Sheets("1")
    Set wsB = wb.Sheets("2")
    Set wsB = wb.Sheets("3")
    
    Set cDest = wsC.Range("A1") 'start pasting here
    
    For Each c In wsA.Range("D1:D" & wsA.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        m = Application.Match(c.Value, wsB.Columns("A"), 0) 'Match is faster than Find
        If Not IsError(m) Then             'got a match?
            wsB.Rows(m).Copy cDest         'copy matched row
            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next paste row
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```